# Water flowing around cylinder exciting circular waves of which wavelength?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am dealing with the following setup: Imagine an upright, fixed cylinder in flowing water of constant and homogneous velocity. "Behind" the cylinder one can imagine ship-like wakes to appear. In a very basic sense I find it natural to assume that the flowing water somwhat excites circular waves at the cylinder, which propagate while being shifted by the flowing water (and ultimately form the wakes). Is this sensible? Now, if circular waves emerge, what wavelength do they have?

I read papers assuming that the mainly contributing wavelength will be $\lambda_{main} = D$ with $D$ being the diameter of the cylinder. What is a solid reasoning for this approach?

Comment: Is this question about vortices or waves? If it's really about waves, what's a "circular wave"?

Comment: @tom10 Imagine a ship driving through water. There are several papers that show that the ship wake is consistant with a Mach cone (for certain conditions of the flow). This leads to the interpretation of circular waves being excited at the moving ship (similar to a nail repetedly impinging on the water surface and moving at the same time). I am asking for the wavelength of the excited waves "at the ship" (or the cylinder) in order to calculate their propagation velocity using the corresponding dispersion relation.